# Why does Porous-tube Nutrient Delivery System cultivation improve nutritional quality of Okinawa spinach (Gyruna bicolor)?

Tags: biochemistry, agriculture, peer-review-journal

I wrote a review paper and it involves in growth system of a plant “Okinawa Spinach (*Gynura bicolor*)”. A research of (Wang, Fu, & Liu, 2015) reported that Porous-tube Nutrient Delivery System (PTNDS) cultivation enhanced calories from 139.5 to 182.3 kJ/100 g dry matter, and carbohydrate from 4.8 to 7.3 g/100 g dry matter and reduced the amount of protein from 7.3 to 4.8 g/100 g dry matter and ash from 1.4 to 1.0 g/ 100 g dry matter, compared with hydroponic culture. PTNDS cultivation also accumulated the nutrition elements of Ca, Cu, Fe and Zn, and reduced Na concentration.

The reviewer asked me that “why the plant grown in PTNDS reduced the total ash but why improved accumulation of Ca, Cu, Fe and Zn.? “My major is food engineering and I’m not expert in this field. 
If this area is your expertise or someone knows the answers? Please help me out with it. Thanks very much.

Wang, M., Fu, Y., & Liu, H. (2015). Nutritional status and ion uptake response of Gynura bicolor DC. between Porous-tube and traditional hydroponic growth systems. Acta Astronautica, 113, 13-21.